# Typeorm global where clause

Tags: javascript, typescript, orm, typeorm

in my database, all tables have a boolean column "active" which is used to know if the row should be returned or not on the query.

As we use TypeORM as our back-end ORM, Is it possible to have a global statement/clause that is "concatenated" on every query made by TypeORM, like:

WHERE column.active = true

So, like this, the rows with the column active with 0 as a value, don't return on TypeORM queries during the main application flow, instead of rewriting it on every queryBuilder or repositories premade queries like "find" or "findOrfail" where we dont even write anything.

- Need to be in TypeORM because it should be returned on manual queries on sgbd and things like this
- We use postgre as SGBD
- Typeorm v0.2.24

Answer (score 0):

This lib supports Scopes for both Active Record pattern (working with Entitiies), and Data Mapper pattern (working with Repositories) (for typeorm both versions 2.x and 3.x). I think this will be very useful for all of you.

[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-scoped)

```js
import { DefaultScopes } from "typeorm-scoped"

@DefaultScopes<User>({
  existed: (qb, alias) => qb.andWhere(`${alias}.deletedAt IS NULL`),
  ...
})
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
  // ...
}

// in Your service

User.find({where: {name: "John"}})
// or
userRepository.find({where: {name: "John"}})

// will produce an SQL query like
// SELECT "User"."id" AS "User_id", "User"."name" AS "User_name" 
// FROM "user" "User" 
// WHERE "User"."name" = ? AND "User"."deletedAt" IS NULL
// -- PARAMETERS: ["John"]
```